# How to enable guake at startup using systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

i made my service

```
/etc/systemd/system/guake.service
```

containing

```
[Unit]
Description=Start guake 

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash guake

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

then i did

```
systemctl start guake.service 
systemctl status guake.service
```

but i get

● guake.service - Start guake
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/guake.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Thu 2015-07-16 21:14:36 SAST; 4s ago
  Process: 10785 ExecStart=/bin/bash guake (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 10785 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)

Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/**init**.py:57: GtkWarning: could...isplay
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keybinder/**init**.py:26: GtkWarning: IA__gdk...failed
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: from _keybinder import *
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keybinder/**init**.py:26: GtkWarning: IA__gdk...failed
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: from _keybinder import *
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc systemd[1]: guake.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc systemd[1]: guake.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc systemd[1]: guake.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc systemd-coredump[10790]: Process 10785 (python2) of user 0 dumped core.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

I also tried setting `WantedBy=multi-user.target` but it has the same error

i am runnig arch linux, how do i get this to startup, thanks all

Comment: Does quake need a GUI to run?  Perhaps you could add it to your .bash_profile instead?

Comment: I'd say you should start it using the auto startup mechanism provided by your DE.

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl enable guake.service
```

cf https://wiki.debian.org/systemd